# Get all css style, link, js and script from html file using ShellScript

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, html

I want to get all JS `<script>` tag inside data as well as `<script src="path/to/js"></script>` or `<script src="http(s)://example.com/to.js"></script>`. same for the `<style>` and `<link href="path/to/css">` or `<link src="http(s)://example.com/to.js">`

Here I can run different commands to get the script block, script link, and same for style and link.

I have tried below where I can get the `script` tag details as well as the script link.

```
sed -n 's/.*\(<script>.*<\/script>\).*/\1/p' path/to/file.html
```

But here it will return from the start of the `<script>` tag to the end of the `</script>`, here if any other context is present in between the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/basscss/8.1.0/css/basscss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <style>
    html, body {
      background: grey;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/1.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href="https://google.com">Hi</a>

  <link href="assets/css/2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    var a = "Hello I'm inclined!";
    console.log(a);
    console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.version);
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/1.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the below outcome with my script `sed` command when the HTML is **minified**, and got ***nothing*** when the HTML is **not minified**

```
<script>var a="Hello I'm inclined!"; console.log(a); console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.version); </script> <script src="assets/js/1.js"></script> <script src="assets/js/2.js"></script>
```

Similar for `<style></style>` and `<link ... rel="stylesheet">`

For this I found below command will only return the CSS link from the `<link ... />` tag:

```
sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' path/to/file.html
```

it returns below output, where the anchor(`<a ...></a>`) tag `href` is also present due to the match case with the regex I used.

And the outcome is from non minified version.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/basscss/8.1.0/css/basscss.css assets/css/1.css https://google.com assets/css/2.css
```

For minified it returns only the last one.

```
assets/css/2.css
```

My expectations of the outcome as given below (for non minified version):

**scripts**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script><script>
    var a = "Hello I'm inclined!";
    console.log(a);
    console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.version);
</script>
<script src="assets/js/1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/2.js"></script>
```

**Styles**

```
<style>
    html, body {
      background: grey;
    }
</style>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/basscss/8.1.0/css/basscss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/css/1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/css/2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Check out my sample [HERE](https://replit.com/@DevAtCN/Get-Script-and-Style-from-HTML-using-ShellScript)

Edit it from [HERE](https://replit.com/join/xdapisqpff-devatcn)

Any other solution will be highly appreciated. (e.g - awk, Python or any other)

Comment: First, parsing HTML with regular expressions (regex) is extremely error prone and notoriously difficult to get right--especially with the HTML some authors write. Second, your regex is poor: `<script>.*</script>` means "take everything as long as possible to sill match", because .* is, by default, _greedy/longest match_. Make it non-greedy, like this `<script>.*?</script>`, so it will stop at the _shortest_ possible match.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How to make it global or multiline search! I have tried with regex101 code generator for sed, but that never worked.

Comment: Style sheets are similar when using (inline) <style>...</style> elements, but more complex when using external style sheets, as not all <link ....> definitions are stylesheets--some may define other link relationships. You will have to process them to find which are stylesheets, and which are not. And I have not mentioned yet the added complexities of matching <script ... /> or <link ... /> instead of <script ....>...</script>, or <link ...> or <link ....>...</link>, or attributes with and without quotation marks, and so on.

Comment: With all the above issues, you are better off using a programming or scripting language, such as C/C++, Perl, Python, etc, and an XML/HTML parser library--preferably one that supports XPath to find any `script`, `style`, or `link` nodes.

Comment: [regex is the wrong tool to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: regex101 just validates that a given regexp works on that site, it doesn't mean that regexp will work in any given command line tool as they all use different regexp variants, have extensions, constraints, options, delimiters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all of the valuable inputs and suggestions. :) I'm trying with other useful language.

Comment: Make sure to include concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question. No links, no images, no videos, just text that we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Comment: You can checkout my sample from here also updated my question to have more information and example. https://replit.com/@DevAtCN/Get-Script-and-Style-from-HTML-using-ShellScript also you can edit from here if you want to https://replit.com/join/xdapisqpff-devatcn

Comment: Again - don't expect anyone to click on external links to help you. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by creating and posting a minimal but comprehensive example in your question that we can copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 0):

All the advice about using XML-aware tools is generally good if you have them and get an answer showing how to use them, otherwise this will probably be adequate for your needs if your input is a subset of XML like you show in your question and `>` doesn't appear in any of your links.

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `\>` word boundary:

```
$ awk -v tag='script' 'BEGIN{RS="</?"tag"\\>"} !(NR%2){print "<"tag $0 RT">"}' file
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var a = "Hello I'm inclined!";
    console.log(a);
    console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.version);
  </script>
<script src="assets/js/1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/2.js"></script>
```

```
$ awk -v tag='style' 'BEGIN{RS="</?"tag"\\>"} !(NR%2){print "<"tag $0 RT">"}' file
<style>
    html, body {
      background: grey;
    }
  </style>
```

```
$ awk -v tag='link' 'BEGIN{RS="<"tag"\\>[^>]*>"} RT{print RT}' file
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/basscss/8.1.0/css/basscss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/1.css">
<link href="assets/css/2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but it returns unexpected results. ```<script
  <style>
    html, body {
      background: grey;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/1.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href="https://google.com">Hi</a>

  <link href="assets/css/2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  >
<script
  <script src="assets/js/1.js">>
<script
</body>
</html>>```

Comment: Are you sure you're using GNU awk (check `awk --version`)? All we have to test with is the example you provide in your question. If that's not adequate for us to test a solution with then update your question to fix that.

Comment: I'm using mac and my `awk` version is `awk version 20070501`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion here also: https://replit.com/@DevAtCN/Get-Script-and-Style-from-HTML-using-ShellScript

Comment: You can join my repl playground and edit from there: https://replit.com/join/xdapisqpff-devatcn

Comment: OK, so you're not using GNU awk as I said was required, you're using a BSD awk on MacOS. Install GNU awk and then try it. Regarding "You can join..." - no, don't post links, just edit your question to include a minimal example we can test with.